# Is it Possible to create one form using PySimpleGUI to fetch data from excel table?

Tags: excel, forms, user-interface, datatable, pysimplegui

Dears,

Is it Possible to create one form using PySimpleGUI to fetch data from excel table ?
I need the reverse process of what has been done in Topic : https://github.com/Sven-Bo/data-entry-form-pysimplegui

Thanks in advance

Comment: No code and xlsx file to demo what your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using the following.  This told me how many rows and columns I read and what the headers (row 0) were.

```
import pandas as pd

sheets=['Sheet1']
df = pd.read_excel(r'\\network\shared\folder\file.xlsx',sheet_name=sheets, header=None)

curSheet = sheets[0] # Sheet1
rows = df[curSheet].shape[0]
cols = df[curSheet].shape[1]
headings = [df[curSheet][i][0] for i in range(cols) ]
#cols = len(col_count = df.shape[1])
print("Total number of rows=", rows)
print("Total number of columns = ", cols)
print("Headings:",headings)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @RAllenAZ, I will add the same to my project and let you know.